# Can't access the key from my hashtable python

Tags: python, class, iterator, hashtable

So I have a hash table class which is fully functioning, now I want to define another function let say will take a parameter of hash_table and print out every keys from my hash table where

```
def to_print(hash_table):
    for a in hash_table:
            if a is not None:
                    print(a)
```

I was told that I need an iterator, so I define an iter function like below:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for item in self.array:
            if item is not None:
                    (key, value)=item
                    return key
```

However, I still can't read through my keys in my hash table.Error is happened at my line 'for a in hash_table:' For the iterator, if I change 'return key' to 'print key', it does print out every key. And I didn't define **next** because I think I don't need it(?)

Can anyone tell me  where's the problem and maybe some hints of it? Thanks in advance.

Eg. my hash table consist of <'apple',6>, <'orange', 7>, my output should print out apple and orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__iter__` must return iterator, try to do something like:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return (item[0] for item in self.array if item is not None)
```